# What does //**/ mean?

Tags: c, c89

I have got snippet of old c-code with that lines (result is just slash sign):

```
putchar('/' //**/ 
    1 / 1 /'\1');
```

Can anyone explain this snippet? What does this symbols mean?

P.S. By the way it compiles well with std=c89 flag in gcc, but not with std=c99.

Comment: Did you find this in production code, or part of an obfuscated C contest entry?

Comment: On my compiler, GCC 4.8.1, it is not compiling.

Comment: @haccks does [for me] when specify std=c89

Comment: @haccks: Did you set it to C89 mode? GCC's default settings include line comments as an extension.

Comment: @user2357112; No. I compiled it in C99 mode.

Comment: I found this code on the Internet just checking alternative solutions of my answers for k&r book.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's a division, followed by an empty comment. In C99 mode, it's a new-style comment, causing a syntax error because there's no division operator now.

Comment: Maybe it's demonstrating different meanings of slash in C.